# undefined method rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, undefined

Getting a undefined method error on user_sponsorship

app/controllers/user_sponsorships_controller.rb:7:in `new'

This is new.html.erb:

```
<% if @event %>
<%= form_for @user_sponsorship, method: :post do |form|  %>
<div class="mike">
<%= form.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event %>
<%= submit_tag "Yes, sponsor event", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", event_path(@event), class: 'btn btn-default'%>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller:

```
class UserSponsorshipsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

def new
    if params[:event_id]
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @user_sponsorship = current_user.user_sponsorship.new(event: @event)
        else
        flash[:error] = "Event required"
     end
end
end
```

And here is the model:

```
class UserSponsorship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event

attr_accessible :user, :event
end
```

I'm fairly new to Rails as you can tell. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is most probably due to this line

```
@user_sponsorship = current_user.user_sponsorship.new(event: @event)
```

user (most probably) has_many user_sponsorships so that line should be

```
@user_sponsorship = current_user.user_sponsorships.new(event: @event)
```

use the plural form which should also be the association name (if you follow the rails convention).

Comment: Oh wow, how silly of me, forgot to make it plural. Thanks for pointing that out, it is working now.